# Access Database design when changing course fee after certain period of time

Tags: microsoft-access

I currently have three tables:

> student
>
> id (pk) , name
>
> course
>
> id (pk) , course_name ,  course_duration , course_fee
>
> student_course
>
> student_course_id (pk) , student_id (fk) , course_id (fk)

if after a certain period of time the course fee changes, then how can I maintain the record of student having previous course fee?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct, from the schema spec, you cannot. you would have to denormalize the Course_Fee table, so that it also appears in the Student_course table (as that is the only table that maps 1-to-1 with the phenoma of a specific student taking a specific class. )

There is an alternative however. 
Imagine in the Course table you had two rows like:

```
...
2,'Intro to CS', '15 weeks', 2000.00
...
5,'Intro to CS', '15 weeks', 2500.00
...
```

so now you could have historical records of students taking a prior version of the course for 2000$ tied to record ID=2, and new students taking the new version at 2500$ tied to ID=5.

Schema expression like your table definitions can't tell you everything about a how a database operates. even after you consider fields, keys, constraints, etc, there is still the way the application USES the table to consider. For instance in this case the app assumes there may be duplicate courses, and use Top(1) in its queries:

```
select Top(1) * from Course order by ID DESC
```

So, can it express it? yes. Is it bad design, yes. Better to denormalize, and better yet to create a course fee table with an active bit, so you can deactivate old fees but still maintain the data and referential integrity.

I would do it as:

```
Student(Id, Name)
Fee(Id, Fee)
Course(Id, course_name , course_duration , FeeId)
StudentCourse(StudentId, CourseId, FeeId)
```

Comment: **thank you, is this design correct...**  [student-> id(pk), name]    [course-> id(pk), name, course_fee_id(fk)]    [course_fee-> course_fee_id(pk), course_id(fk) , course_fee, date_added]   [student_course-> student_id(fk), course_id(fk), course_fee_id(fk), discount_receive]

Comment: that will work with the caveat that when you join Studentcourses and Courses, you must select the fee from the StudentCourses relation. Probably the best structure would be to remove the Fee from both tables, and create a table of fees. Then in the course and StudentCourses tables, add FeeID as an FK to Fees. that way you are still 3rd normal form, every course knows its current fee, every student knows what they paid when they paid it, and there is no potential ambiguity. See my latest edit for details.